# matplotlib animation module for creating dynamically updated plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to create a plot, which will dynamically update after every 0.1 second, thereby creating an animation or dynamically updated plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y=np.random.rand(101,11)
x=np.linspace(0,11,num=11)

plt.figure()
#plt.ion()
for i in range(y.shape[0]):
    plt.cla()
    plt.axis([0,1.0,0,2.0])
    plt.plot(x,y[i],'k')
    plt.cla()
```

This method works, but I am wondering about whether [animation](https://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html) module is better way to create this plot? Please comment how to use `animation` module to achieve this result. Also, does `plt.ion()` has any effect in this case? Because there is no difference even if `plt.ion()` is commented out.

Running using ipython on Windows.

Comment: It all depends on where and how you run this code. If it is within a script, `plt.ion()` is probably needed, as well as `plt.draw()` at some place. Since you say that the above is working, I suppose you run it somewhere else? But we don't have that information. Animation is often better suited because it is more robust, but again it depends. Without further information on the use case, this is more an opinionated question and hence off-topic. As to how to convert the code to use FuncAnimation: there are just so many similar questions around that I don't think we need to give another answer.

Comment: Running on ipython.

Comment: IPython has turned on the interactive mode by default; hence there is no need to turn it on via `plt.ion()`. You will gain something by using `FuncAnimation` because it allows you to easily set the interval to 0.1 seconds.